# How can I find out how many objects have been created from a class before in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object

How can I find out how many objects have been created from a class before *in C++?*

Comment: Define a static member counter that is going to increase by one in every class constructor call.

Comment: @101010 Don't forget copy constructor.

Comment: I don't know why this was put on hold for too broad. A short, specific answer was indeed provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use this base class:

```
template<class T>
class Counter
{
public:
    Counter()
    {
        ++count;
    }

    Counter(const Counter&)
    {
        ++count;
    }

    static size_t GetCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

private:
    static size_t count;
};

template<class T>
size_t Counter<T>::count = 0;
```

Inherit from it and pass your class type as a template parameter. This is to get a unique count per class type.

```
class MyClass : public Counter<MyClass>
{
};
```

Now you can count the number of times your class is constructed without having to modify its own constructors or possibly forgetting to increment the count in one of them.

Don't delete through a pointer to `Counter` as it lacks a virtual destructor.

Comment: CRTP. Love it for this kind of problems. Shouldn't be there also a `--count` placed in a virtual destructor? Also the copy operator is missed.

Comment: @skypjack It's up to the user if they want to count the total number of objects ever created or the current amount. `operator=` doesn't change the number of objects in existence.

Comment: Why not? I don't get you.

Comment: @skypjack `T x, y;` 2 objects in existence. `x = y;` 2 objects in existence.

Comment: Thanks bro ;) @NeilKirk

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `static int instanceCount;` member variable, and increment it in each of your class constructor functions:

```
class MyClass {
     static int instanceCount = 0;
public:
      MyClass() {
          ++instanceCount;
      }

      MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) {
          ++instanceCount;
          // Do copy code ...
      }

      static int getCreated() { return instanceCount; }
 };
```

Comment: `MyClass a; MyClass b = a;` what's the count?

Comment: @NeilKirk As I've mentioned _in each of your constructor functions_.

Comment: In your example you haven't incremented it in each of your class's constructors.

Comment: Now the user must implement a whole copy constructor even if the default generated one was correct. That's not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you Just define Static integer value and put it in the constructor like variable++

```
class count_opjs{
Public:
 static int counter;
 constructor(){
   counter++;
 }
}
// Initialize static member of class count_opjs
int count_opjs::counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather copy you an example from the wiki page dedicated to a well know idiom, the CRTP.

It's far more complete of whatever I could write for myself at midnight. Moreover, I find that all the other responses miss something indeed, and that's why I add one more response to the list.

```
template <typename T> struct counter {
    static int objects_created;
    static int objects_alive;

    counter() {
        ++objects_created;
        ++objects_alive;
    }

    counter(const counter&) {
        ++objects_created;
        ++objects_alive;
    }

protected:
    ~counter() {
        --objects_alive;
    }
};

template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created( 0 );
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );

class X : counter<X> { // ... };
class Y : counter<Y> { // ... };
```

I guess this is a complete one, having both a counter for created objects and for still alive ones.

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) the original link.

Comment: `operator=` does not change the number of objects in existence.

Comment: Why not? I don't get you.